# Naming executables in cmake

Tags: cmake

I'm working on a project and decided to port it to CMake. While I was configuring I used the placeholder build name build; no problems were encountered. But after I switched the name to `S&W`, CMake wouldn't let me build. It produced the error message:

```
[cmake] CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:28 (add_executable):
[cmake]   The target name "S&W" is reserved or not valid for certain CMake features,
[cmake]   such as generator expressions, and may result in undefined behavior.
```

I'm pretty sure the name `S&W` is not reserved by CMake.

So Why is this happening? Can I do anything to fix this error?

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.14)
project(S&W)

include_directories("source")
include_directories("dependencies/include")

file(GLOB_RECURSE SRC "source/*.cpp")
LINK_DIRECTORIES("dependencies/lib/x86")

if ( MINGW )
set(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS  "-static-libgcc -static-libstdc++")
LINK_LIBRARIES("mingw32")
endif ( MINGW )

LINK_LIBRARIES("libSDL2main.a")
LINK_LIBRARIES("libSDL2.dll.a")
LINK_LIBRARIES("libSDL2_mixer.dll.a")

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} ${SRC})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error tells that you cannot declare a **target** which contains some special symbols (`&` in your case).

However, this doesn't mean that you cannot generate the **file** with given name. Just create "normal" executable target, but assign [OUTPUT_NAME](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.7/prop_tgt/OUTPUT_NAME.html) property for it:

```
add_executable(SW ${SRC})
set_target_properties(SW PROPERTIES OUTPUT_NAME "S&W")
```

Comment: @Tsyverrev Doesn't seem's like codes answers working. it still won't build, i'm getting the error message  [build] [  9%] Linking CXX executable "S
[build] 'W.exe\""' is not recognized as an internal or external command,

Comment: Hm, it seems that MinGW doesn't like `&` symbol in the filename. Or CMake generates wrong command line for MinGW.

Answer (score 1):

You have forbidden character in target name, namely `&`.

Take a look at documentation about [cmake target naming](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/policy/CMP0037.html), this paragraph in particular:

```
Target names may contain upper and lower case letters, numbers, the underscore
character (_), dot(.), plus(+) and minus(-). As a special case, ALIAS targets
and IMPORTED targets may contain two consequtive colons.
```